# Connect with postgreSQL schema

Tags: postgresql, go, database-schema

I am looking to connect and query to a PostgreSQL. But I only want to connect to a particular **[Schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html)**.

As per the doc (**JDBC**) we can use

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase?searchpath=myschema
```

or **update** As of 9.4 you can specify the url with the new currentSchema parameter like so:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase?currentSchema=myschema
```

But I am unable to do so with **golang** SQL driver;

As per the documents, we can also use `SET search_path TO myschema,public;`
 But I only want to declare it for once during initializing but I think this needs to be executed every time for new connection.

Also I am using following code please help me identify the correct parameters to be passed to this in order to only connect with schema

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", `dbname=`+s.settings.Database+
` user=`+s.settings.Username+` password=`+s.settings.Password+
` host=`+s.settings.Url+` sslmode=disable`)
```

Adding `currentSchema=myschema` or `searchpath=myschema` is not working!

Is there a way I can only connect to a particular database-schema in GO

Comment: jdbc is java, not go

Comment: @Woot4Moo, that I know that's why I mentioned *as per doc*; sorry if it was not clear, but I have mentioned the code snippet below I tried adding those `currentSchema=myschema` to the statement but its not working

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should add `search_path=myschema` to `dataSourceName`

P.S. better use `fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d dbname=%s user=%s password='%s' sslmode=disable search_path=%s", ...)` instead ``` ``+`` ```

Comment: Adding search_path in my postgres url worked for me, thanks !

Answer (score 5):

Set Search_path is right and you do it once. ie:

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres",
    "host=localhost dbname=Test sslmode=disable user=postgres password=secret")
if err != nil {
   log.Fatal("cannot connect ...")
}
defer db.Close()
db.Exec(`set search_path='mySchema'`)

rows, err := db.Query(`select blah,blah2 from myTable`)
...
```

Comment: I am using 
`
 db, err := sql.Open("postgres", `dbname=`+dbName+` user=`+username+` password=`+password+` host=`+host+` sslmode=disable`)
 if err != nil {
  panic("Main db connection failed")
 }

 db.SetMaxIdleConns(40)
 db.SetMaxOpenConns(160)
`
So there are many parallel connections, I am doubtful or can you explain me will executing this `db.Exec(`set search_path='mySchema'`)` will set schema for every connection?

Comment: @AbhishekSoni you are writing what I did in a different way. That exec is needed once per connection. Like you need to Open() per connection you need to Exec per db once.

Comment: I am confused with the functionality of connections but indeed wanted to know that `db.Exec(`set search_path='mySchema'`)` is required **once** per *OPEN* and not per connection (as in example i am setting maxConns to 40 so need to execute it 40 times)?

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply test and see?

Comment: @AbhishekSoni you should use a transaction